# pg_restore giving an error (using default compression in pg_dump)

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I did a `pg_dump` using this command -

`pg_dump -U postgres -d dbtest --create -n dbtest -Fc | gzip -9 -c > /backup/dbtest.gz`

I am trying to restore it using this command -

`pg_restore -h myhostname -p 5432 -U postgres -d dbtest -Fc dbtest.gz &> Restore.log`

But I am getting an error that states - `[archiver] did not find magic string in file header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gzipped the file after backing it up. You need to unzip it first.